# Integrate location navigation into site

Tags: website-design, gui-design

In our classifieds site we search by a string (ie. iphone) and we see the search results, as seen on the screenshot. The initial search displays everything in the United States.

To this search result, I would like to add navigation by location.

This is a possible scenario:

I'm from Brooklyn and I'm looking for a gold iphone 6 for $50.

- I search in *Brooklyn* (part of New York City), but nothing.
- I then search in *Manhattan* (also part of New York City), but nothing.
- I then search in *All of New Work City*, but nothing.
- I then search in *All of New York*, but still nothing.
- I then search *Massachusetts* (state close to New York), but still nothing.
- Finally, I search in *All of US* and I find a listing in Miami.

The point is that I can search in a specific place (ie. Brooklyn) or in the area where this county is (NYC).

We previously had a treeview that was perfect, but it was way down at the bottom. As you can see from the screenshot, the left header has too much stuff already (category treeview and search criteria) so I cannot add the treeview there.

So how would I be able to add navigation by location here?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is a bit convoluted, you could simply ask the user to add locations and/or within certain ranges. For example:

[image]

or some quick mock using your own site:

[image]

or you could use ranges or whatever, just be direct and concise and try not to confuse the user with *if else* conditionals, that is something you need to take care in your backend, but your front end has to be as easy as possible

Answer (score 0):

The flow you're describing is a user trying to buy an iPhone. He want local results first, but will consider driving a bit further away as well.

First thing that comes to mind is don't filter by location, sort by distance. However, I think sorting by price will be an overwhelming preference here, so that's out.

Seeing as the process is one-directional, meaning the user will always start with the closest, smallest geo-unit and move outwards and further, they don't really need to decide anything at all.

**Add a link** at the end of the results (or a lot more prominent if there are zero results) to broaden the search.
This way the user doesn't need to worry about entering the next level up, not about missing out on a good deal just beyond state lines.

You understood the user's thinking and flow of action and made their life easier, not just moved some boxes around to make the dropdown more affordable.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ecg.close5

Install this app and check it out. It is a classifieds app with a similar use case. They have just added options like - within 5 miles, 10 miles, 15 miles, etc.

Similarly, you can divide your results based on region, and at the same time display the number of items found in each division. 
For better UX, the location can be auto-populated, and then the field can be edited if the user wants to. 
Only the regions that have results should be active and the nearest one should be auto-selected.

Check the mockup below.

[image]

Providing a long tree structure will add more cognitive load to the users. Almost all trending classifieds sites avoid tree structure